# Запуск программ в visual basic

Tags: visual-basic

Как запустить программу и дождаться ее завершения?

Comment: @Магомед, видимо вопрос с ***подвохом***

>*Уточните свой вопрос*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
Public Sub RunProcess(ByVal ProcessPath As String)
        Dim objProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
        Try
            objProcess = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
            objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ProcessPath
            objProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            objProcess.Start()

            objProcess.WaitForExit()

            objProcess.Close()
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Could not start process " & ProcessPath, "Error")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[Ссылка на источник.](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5879)